# How to check for duplicate records in a Django admin inline?

Tags: django, django-admin

How do you do perform validation checks involving multi-inline forms in Django admin inlines?

For example, I have a simple Parent/Child model, with an admin interface showing the children in an inline table on the parent's admin change page.

Each child has a "name" field which must be unique.

On child model, I've implemented a `clean()` method to enforce this rule, raising a `forms.ValidationError` so the error is displayed in a user-friendly fashion in the admin UI. This method is called from the model's `full_clean()` method, which is called by Django admin during the validation step for each inline form. So, individually, if the user attempts to create a child record, that check caches the error.

However, since Django runs the validation for each inline table separately before saving the records, it doesn't cache duplicates in the new data. So if the user creates two new inline rows and enters duplicate names in each of those rows, they pass the validation check, but then when Django goes to actually save the records, it encounters the exception, which is now handled like a very user-unfriendly 500 error.

Is there an easy way to fix this? Looking through Django's code, I'm not seeing anything obvious in the `_changeform_view()` that houses most of the admin form validation logic.

Presumably, I'd override something on the inline's ModelForm, but even the `clean` method on that only validates the fields for a single record, not across multiple records.

Comment: Is the uniqueness a constraint on the model? Can you show the clean method? The admin usually handles this unique constraint validation for you even for inlines

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem myself and spent quite a while on a solution.
I'm not sure if you found an answer (*since it has been 5 months since you have asked*) but either way I think that sharing my solution might be beneficial so here you go:

I tried to override the `clean()` method of various classes also but to no avail. Then I found this page ([Customize Save In Django Admin Inline Form](https://gist.github.com/shymonk/5d4467bbc7d08dd7f6f4?permalink_comment_id=3998565)) which suggested overriding the `save_new_objects` and `save_existing_objects` methods on a CustomInLineFormSet class.

So in admin.py I added the following method to a CustomInLineFormSet class (or in your case this would be intended for the Child model):

```
class ChildInLineFormSet(BaseInLineFormSet):
    def save_new_objects(self, commit=True):
        saved_instances = super(ChildInLineFormSet, self).save_new_objects(commit)
        if commit:
            for instance in saved_instances:
                instance.delete()
                try:
                    ChildModel.objects.get(name=instance.name)
                except ChildModel.DoesNotExist:
                    instance.save()
                else:
                    saved_instances.remove(instance)
                    
        return saved_instances
```

Also, wherever you have declared your InLine class you must also add the definition for the formset field:

```
class ChildInLine(admin.StackedInline):
    formset = ChildInLineFormSet #add this to whatever you already have
```

I hope this helps!

EDIT: I did a bit more digging on this: Using a custom formset is *NOT* necessary after all.

You can override the save_formset() method in the admin class and and should obtain the same result without having to save the models to the database:

```
class ParentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        unique_names = []
        for obj in formset.deleted_objects:
            obj.delete()
        for instance in instances:
            if (instance.name) in unique_names:
                instance.delete()
                continue
            unique_names.append(instance.name)
            instance.save()
        formset.save_m2m()
```